# Tying a Tie on Shabbos

Tags: shabbat, clothing, melacha-creative-work, tying-knots-kosheir

How should one tie a tie on Shabbos (or yom tov) so that it doesn't have any knot problems?

In other words there are [lots of ways to tie a tie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_85_Ways_to_Tie_a_Tie). I was wondering which of these are okay for use on Shabbos.

Answer (score 4):

The strictest opinion is that any knot tied on shabbos has to be able to be untied with one pull. Most ways of tying a necktie can be untied with one pull provided the neck isn't inside the loop :).

Comment: this answer could be improved with citation of a source.

Comment: The half-Windsor, which is common, cannot be untied with a single pull even if a neck is not within the loop. The four-in-hand, another common one, _can_ (I think) be untied with one pull. http://www.tie-a-tie.net/ has more info on various knots, though it doesn't indicate which can be opened with a single pull.

Comment: I tie half windsors. If you pull the short end out of the loop and keep pulling the know is gone.

@Isaac Moses, the source is a book called "knot on shabbos" that is all about the topology of halachic knots on shabbos.

Comment: Please add your source to your answer, preferably including a link to more information about the book.

Comment: Will do, as soon as I get home to look up the author and ISBN.

Comment: The idea you are bringing down is based on R' Meir in the first mishna in v'elu hak'sharim, the halacha we practice is based on the tanna kamma.

Answer (score 2):

One may tie (and untie, not that you asked) any knot that isn't strong and is meant to be untied within twenty-four hours of its being tied. *Sh'miras Shabas K'hilchasah* 15:52, :55. (However, :58 seems to contradict this.) [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR) for a final ruling, as always; in particular, *SSK* doesn't [AFAICT](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/AFAICT) indicate what's considered strong.

Comment: Here are two articles (with sources) on knot tying, which discuss what is considered strong, etc. http://www.shemayisrael.co.il/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos7_40.htm and http://www.shemayisrael.com/parsha/ostroff/archives/shabbos7_41.htm

Answer (score 2):

This may be stretched logic, but: R' Tzvi Sobolofsky said in his [children in halacha](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/720224/Rabbi_Zvi_Sobolofsky/Care_of_Children_on_Shabbat) lecture, that a diaper is a kesher sh'aino shel kayama because it will be dirty and thus removed in less than 24 hrs.  This seems to ignore the fact that the same closure, if left alone for 24 hrs would probably stay closed.  So the same can be said of a tie.  If you are in the habit of weaing your tie for more than 24 hrs straight, this could still be a problem, but what nut wears a tie for 24 hours straight?

Comment: Some people may leave their ties knotted even when they take them off for the night and then just slip them on in the morning. One would have to make sure not (groan) to do this on Saturday nights if it was tied on Shabbat.