# Tying a Bow-Tie on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, clothing, tying-knots-kosheir

Is one allowed to tie and wear a bow-tie on Shabbos?

Bow-ties are not intended to remain tied between uses (I'm not even sure if it's possible to loosen it and slip it off the neck, like one can do with a regular necktie). This generally means that the knot is considered a Kesher She'eino Shel Kayoma (non-permanent know), which would make the knot a permissible one to tie on Shabbos. On the other hand, it's possible that the knot itself might still be considered "too strong of a knot", which even though it's intended to be undone in a short amount of time, would still be forbidden (i.e. [tying shoes with a double knot](http://www.aish.com/atr/Tying-Shoelaces.html)).

Related: [Tying a Tie on Shabbos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6965/tying-a-tie-on-shabbos)

Comment: I understood that the problem with tying relates to permanent knots and not bows, which are not permanent and aren't knots. (If tying bow ties are prohibited, we would lose our *chazzan*. He can't sing without wearing a bow tie.)

Answer (score 2):

[Halachipedia](http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Koshair#Permissible_knots) citing O.C. 317:5, and other sources, says:

> 11. A bow-knot, slipknot, or a single-knot isn’t a true Kesher-bind and is permissible even if it does remain in place for a while. [21]
>       For example: a ribbon on a gift, a single bind on a shopping bag or
>       garbage liner.
> 12. It is permitted to tie a slip knot or bow without a underlying knot even if it is tight and meant never to be undone. [22]
> 13. After tying a bow knot (a bow on top of a single knot), as is common when tying one's shoes, one may not tie a second bow on top of
>       the bow knot. [23] Others permit tying this knot since it can still be
>       untied with a single hand by pulling on the end of the string. [24]

Further:

> Many authorities hold that it is permissible to tie a necktie on
>   Shabbat if one usually unties it within 24 hours. However, if one
>   doesn't usually untie it within 24 hours, some say that if one intends
>   to untie it within 24 hours it is permitted, while others write that
>   one should tie it from before Shabbat and put it on and take it off by
>   just tightening and loosening the side which goes around the neck,
>   however, one shouldn't untie it on Shabbat

Having stated this, I am aware that there are a few ways to tie a bow tie as well as a regular tie. Looking at the diagram on [this page](http://www.dispatch.com/content/stories/life_and_entertainment/2012/12/31/tie-one-on.html), as well as watching how my shul's chazzan makes his bow tie, which pretty much follows the diagram, this looks like a slip-knot or bow which unravels quite easily with a simple tug. Based on that style of bow, it seems to match up with what Halchipedia says is permitted on Shabbat.